# Moving the "model" SQL Server database on an Azure VM prevents service startup

Tags: sql-server, azure

This is likely the result of an on-prem mind attempting to mould the cloud inappropriately... hoping someone can help me out of a borked SQL configuration:

- I started with an Azure VM template with SQL Server 2017 Developer
- Next, I successfully moved "tempdb" to the (standard) "Temporary Storage" drive
- I wished to then move the "model" DB to pattern future database additions (using ALTER DATABASE commands, then copying the mdf/ldf), and there the trouble started:

  - The service refuses to start, event log reports "The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
    %%945"
  - Attempting a start from the command line with "-f -T3608" reports "ex_dump_if_requested: Exception raised, major=52, minor=43, state=8, severity=22, attempting to create symptom dump"

How can I instruct the service (without it being started) to look for the "model" database files in the previous location?

Comment: this doesnt have to do anything with the cloud. its just a vm, it doesnt differ in anyway to a vm on prem. you misconfigured something and blame the cloud for that.

Comment: Was hoping for a little better response than that - especially from an MVP. Pretty sure Azure VMs do differ from a VM on-prem (see SqlIaasExtension.Service.exe) - but I'm no expert, and frankly don't care. Because yes, I misconfigured something - hence _the first sentence of the post_ - really, I'm not hiding that. And apologies if it sounds like I'm blaming the cloud... because I don't see anywhere I'm blaming anyone but myself. _I_ screwed this up, and don't know how to unscrew it...

Comment: well, i'm not really a sql guy, i'm just telling you that you screwed up and its really easier to start a new vm with sql. the way sql server works has nothing to do with it running in AWS\Azure\Google\On Prem\etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah HA - I am not smart ;)

The root of my problem was that I copied/moved the INCORRECT model.mdf and modellog.ldf files. (There are several on the system.) I (lazily) used Windows search to find the files - and did not notice that it found ones in a "template" folder. I should have used the ones in the %Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA folder.

Once I copied the CORRECT model files over, everything started up just fine!

Many thanks to @SQLSocialite who was a good pair of second eyes...